# Functional/reasonable method for updating a/multiple/changing (kinda) binary tree in F#

Tags: functional-programming, f#, binary-tree

=========

### Where I am

I'm currently working on programming a (very) small game that I've previously written in C#. I don't have much experience with F# and functional-programming in general as I more or less stumbled across it late this summer. Otherwise I have at least a few years of experince with programming in general and understanding of "more advanced than basic"-concepts and patterns.

### Game logic

Well well. Let me show you a picture first.
[image: Simple diagram describing basic game logic]

In this game, the player will place "nodes" on a map and connect them as shown above. Some nodes (marked IN*) will "output" a constant value, while other nodes (ADD and MULT) will take two inputs and produce an output, for example the middle node takes 5 and 9 and adds them, outputting 14.

**Any name suggestions better than "IN"? They will always represent numbers 0<n<10. Is there a name for such numbers in english? (Would be "ental", "one-numbers", in Swedish)*

The player will be also be able to, as shown, connect a node's output to more than one (infinite) node. One node may even connect its output to both inputs of another node. Hence the "(kinda) binary tree" (Is there maybe a name for this?). Nodes can never be connected as to produce a loop, so if A outputs to B, B cannot output to A.

It's important that this structure may change in any way, at any time. There is no guarantee that all nodes are connected to a common root. Multiple "trees" may exist and may then be connected at any time.

### Prior solutions (oop)

When I've solved this before in C#, I had a List of Node-objects. All Node-objects had two possible inputs and an output. When I updated this, I think I looked for nodes without outputs to determine all roots. Then I, recursively called something like `.GetValue()` or `.Update()` on the current node's inputs, which then did the same for its inputs and so on. Not perfect though, thanks to this "(kinda) binary tree"-structure but it worked.

### Problem / Main question

How would I implement this in a more functional way in F#? I think I need a list, at least closer to the UI, but as I don't think reference-types such as classes is "the functional way" I'd rather use Records for each Node. I am aware that I theoretically could store IDs for referenced nodes in a node's input-fields. This seems kinda unsafe and bulky though as there is nothing (that I know of) that can guarantee that the stored IDs actually match an existing node, and that all nodes' IDs are unique.

I don't think (at least not easily) that I can store copies of other nodes instead of IDs as the nodes will have first-class functions to define their behaviour, and, as far as I know, they cannot be compared for equality.

Is there any established functional method for dealing with this sort of structure or is there maybe another better way to approach this? I've thought about storing the connections instead but I don't think that'll help in any way.

Ofcourse, I'm very greatful for any help and advice! And please tell me if I'm attempting to solve the wrong problem! Thank you!

Comment: There would definitely be other ways to do this, but you might want to take a look at the [Dataflow Task Parallel Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library).  From your description, I _think_ it might be quite a good fit.

Comment: @Jarak Thanks! From my first breif read it seems maybe a bit overkill, I don't need this to be async or anything. I will read a bit further though so I really understand what it's about.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/ScottHutchinson/TreeBuilding/blob/master/TreeBuilding.fs

Comment: @ScottHutchinson Will def. check it out. Thanks!

Comment: From the picture and your description it looks like a directed acyclic graph (DAG). It's not a tree because there are many roots and many inputs but also it's less than a full graph as it's acyclic making it easier to deal with. A common pattern when splitting a computational task which would make sense for the Dataflow task library but also used in luigi, spark. Perhaps having name will make it easier to search for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question it seems what is being asked for is what is called an [direct acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph).

This is a common pattern in distributed computing and used in tools like AirFlow, Luigi, Spark and Dataflows.

Trees are great to work with but not all problems can be represented as trees. Graphs kind of sucks to work with in FP. Directed Acyclic Graph are something in the middle that is decent to work with.

Below is a simple approach for representing a DAG in F#. I think it's too simplistic for the scenario outlined in the question but perhaps it can help @Evil_Bengt in the right direction.

```
module FsDag =
  type ReducerOperation = Add|Multiply

  type DAG =
    // Input is a DAG node containing constant input
    | Input   of int
    // Reducer DAG nodes aggregates a list of DAG inputs
    //  using a reducer operation. Reducer is a common expression
    //  for operations that operates on collections and produce value.
    //  Common reducer functions are List.reduce, List.fold and List.sum
    | Reducer of ReducerOperation*DAG list

  // "Constructor" functions for DAG nodes
  let input     i         = Input   i
  let reducer   rop dags  = Reducer (rop, dags)
  let add           dags  = reducer Add      dags
  let multiply      dags  = reducer Multiply dags

  // Evals a DAG into an int value
  let rec eval n =
    match n with
    | Input   i             -> i
    | Reducer (op, sources) ->
      let r, z =
        match op with
        | Add       -> ( + ), 0
        | Multiply  -> ( * ), 1
      sources |> List.map eval |> List.fold r z

open FsDag

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
  let i0 = input 5
  let i1 = input 9
  let dag = multiply [(add [i0; i1]); i1]

  printfn "DAG  %A" dag
  printfn "Eval %A" (eval dag)
  0
```